# Best API to see if an account exist in Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I have a list of usernames, with this list, I want to see if an Instagram account with such username exists programmatically.

What is the best tool (or an API) to use to input a list of usernames and parse the information of whether an account exists or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What language are you looking to use?

Here's something that could work in Python 3:

```py
import requests

username = "whatever"
response = requests.get("https://instagram.com/" + username + "/")
if response.status_code == 404 :
    #the username isn't taken
```

Or if you're strictly looking for lists you could do:

```py
import requests

notTaken = []
list = ["username1", "username2", "username3", "etc..."]
for i in list :
    response = requests.get("https://instagram.com/" + i + "/")
        if response.status_code == 404 :
            notTaken.append(i)
```

Then, `notTaken` would be a list of usernames that arent taken, you can do whatever you want with it, for example:

```py
print(notTaken)
```

Or

```py
for i in notTaken :
    print(i)
```

If you have the list in a file, and they are each on a separate line, you can do this, if they are using a separator, just change the separator variable and make it equal to whatever the separator is

```py
import requests
filePath = "./list.txt"
separator = "\n" #this means newline, but you could use "," or ";" or whatever
list = open(filePath, "r").read().split(seperator)
notTaken = []
for i in list :
    response = requests.get("https://instagram.com/" + i + "/")
        if response.status_code == 404 :
            notTaken.append(i)
```

Comment: Not  a good solution. Too many requests leads to error 429

Answer (score 1):

As I known don't have any api can do it. But you can write a program request to check `https://www.instagram.com/`+username+`/`. It's may be help you check this user is exist or not and get some information about number of posts, followers, following. Good luck!

Comment: Quick tip - is you add `?__a=1` on to the end of this URL, you get  JSON returned.

Comment: FYI, that doesn't seem to work any more as appending results in this cryptic plaintext response:


for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"lid":"7349675374577760541"}

Answer (score 0):

In Shell I use the following command to see if the user exist:

```
curl -L -s https://www.instagram.com/username.here/ | grep -c "the page may have been removed"
```

Find a way to use this Shell command in Python script, I believe there is a way such `os.system('Shell command here')` to use bash command in Python script but it seems deprecated.